# ID not defined at HTMLElement.onclick polymer inside element

Tags: polymer-2.x, floating-action-button, paper-dialog

When running the onclick open with a FAB, i'm able to open an dialog, as long as i run it inside the index.html. But when I've created an element, and moved the fab and dialog inside this element, I'm prompt with

```
CarDialog not defined at HTMLElement.onclick polymer inside element

<paper-fab icon="maps:directions-car" onclick="carDialog.open()" class="blue"></paper-fab>
    <paper-dialog no-overlap id="carDialog">
        <paper-toolbar>
            <div slot="top" class="title">Title</div>
            <paper-icon-button slot="top" icon="more-vert" on-tap="moreAction"></paper-icon-button>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div class="car-img">
            <object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/car-large.svg">
            </object>
        </div>
    </paper-dialog>
```

This code works inside index.html but if I move it inside an element it stops.

```
<car-dialog-layout></car-dialog-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using on-tap instead of onclick, and toggle the dialog.

```
on-tap="openCarDialog"
...
 openCarDialog() {
    this.$.carDialog.toggle();
  }
```